# The fastest way to enumerate elements when each of them requires information from previous elements

Tags: c#, performance

I have to calculate stuff for 50 elements. Each of them requires the previous 20 elements. Look at the following code:

```cs
var klines = _client.GetKlines(bot.Symbol, bot.Interval, limit: 51).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList(); // 50 elements

for (int i = 0; i < klines.Count; i++)
{
    var candles = _client.GetKlines(bot.Symbol, bot.Interval, endTime: klines[i].OpenTime, limit: 20).Data;

    decimal SMA5 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(candles.TakeLast(5).ToList());
    decimal SMA10 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(candles.TakeLast(10).ToList());
    decimal SMA20 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(candles.TakeLast(20).ToList());

    Console.WriteLine($"OpenTime: {klines[i].OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | MA5: {decimal.Round(SMA5, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)} | MA10: {decimal.Round(SMA10, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)} | MA20: {decimal.Round(SMA20, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");
}
```

I'm pulling data from the servers on each iteration with `_client.GetKlines`. The fastest way would be to get the data at once and then process it. For example, instead of getting 50 elements in the beginning, I will get 70, because I'm only missing the first 20 for the first element. The rest of the elements are contained in the list.

Something like:

```cs
var klines = _client.GetKlines(bot.Symbol, bot.Interval, limit: 51 + 20).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList(); // 50 elements + previous 20 for the first element

for (int i = 0 + 20; i < klines.Count; i++)
{
    // process elements from the existing records, instead of _client.GetKlines everytime
}
```

What would be the fastest way to do that? Performance-wise.

Edit: Working code, just like I wanted it. Can it be optimized more?

```cs
int j = 0;
for (int i = 19; i < klines.Count; i++)
{
    var candles = klines.Skip(j).Take(20);

    decimal SMA5 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(candles.TakeLast(5).ToList());
    decimal SMA10 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(candles.TakeLast(10).ToList());
    decimal SMA20 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(candles.TakeLast(20).ToList());

    Console.WriteLine($"OpenTime: {klines[i].OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | MA5: {decimal.Round(SMA5, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)} | MA10: {decimal.Round(SMA10, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)} | MA20: {decimal.Round(SMA20, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");
    j++;
}
```

Comment: You ask a question in the title, answer it, then ask it again for clarification. Yes you need to get all the data, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @MichaelRandall, I want to know what the best way is. There are many possibilities, e.g. Parallel.For, processing the Liist from the opposite side etc. And I didn't answer it, at least not with code.

Comment: How much time does your current code take to run?

Comment: @mortb, the first code takes a lot because it does requests everytime with `_client.GetKlines`. I don't even have to put a StopWatch. It takes a second or two on each iteration. Imagine doing that for 500 elements. I don't know how to do the second example yet.

Comment: Try to put `.ToList()` at the end of the statement `var candles = _client.GetKlines(bot.Symbol, bot.Interval, endTime: klines[i].OpenTime, limit: 20).Data;` not having `.ToList()` might result in that every usage of the variable `candles` makes a new remote call

Comment: @mortb, you didn't get me. `var candles = _client.GetKlines(bot.Symbol, bot.Interval, endTime: klines[i].OpenTime, limit: 20).Data;` should not be there at all. I will add additional explanation with an example to the question.

Comment: Yes of course it would be better to have less calls to the remote resource. But it is hard for us to know if it will work, for each call in the loop you use `endTime: klines[i].OpenTime` which you don't have at the start

Comment: @mortb, ignore that. Imagine there are 70 elements in that list and the loop should start at index 20 because the first element should always have previous 20.

Comment: Not sure what you want help with. If you change the code to just do one remote call it will probably be drastically faster.

Comment: @mortb, edited the question with working code like I wanted it. I just want it more optimized. Or at least to be improved look-wise.

Comment: Did you test the implementation below?

Comment: @mortb, tested only the queue part, but in a bit different way, thanks for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I try to implement your behavior using a `Queue<int>` to have less `Skip` and `Take` calls. The function name `ToRanges` was the best I could come up with for now. You have to test the code to see if it fits your needs.

```
var klines = _client.GetKlines(bot.Symbol, bot.Interval, limit: 51 + 20).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList(); // 50 elements + previous 20 for the first element

var ranges = ToRanges(klines, 20);
var smaData = ranges.Select(r => new {
    OpenTime = r.First().OpenTime.ToLocalTime(),
    SMA5 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(r.TakeLast(5)), 
    SMA10 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(r.TakeLast(10)),
    SMA20 = ExponentialMovingAverage.SMA(r)
});

foreach(var item in smaData)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"OpenTime: {item.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | MA5: {decimal.Round(item.SMA5, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)} | MA10: {decimal.Round(item.SMA10, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)} | MA20: {decimal.Round(item.SMA20, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");
}


private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> ToRanges(IEnumerable<int> list, int rangeSize)
{
    var queue = new Queue<int>(splitSize);
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
        if(queue.Count == rangeSize)
        {
            yield return queue;
            queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```